# What bash glob pattern matches all files and directories in the current directory except . (current directory) and .. (parent directory)?

Tags: bash, sh, glob, file-globs

What is a bash glob pattern that will match all files and directories in the current directory, **except** for `.` (current directory) and `..` (parent directory)?

e.g., given the following files/directories:

```
.
..
.my_dot_directory
.my_dot_file
my_directory
my_file
```

I want a glob that will return:

```
$ ls -d <my_glob>
.my_dot_directory
.my_dot_file
my_directory
my_file
```

Comment: It would be much easier just to check for those special cases in the code rather than try to make a complicated glob.

Comment: * .??* handles 99.9% of cases.

Comment: `(shopt -s dotglob; ls -d *)`

Comment: for a shell without nullglob, I think you'll always have to check anything was matched (eg. `*` didn't just return `*` and that there isn't actually a file literally called `*`)

Comment: Also see the [dotglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#dotglob) section in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).